# primefaces datatable selectionMode multiple not working with mojarra

Tags: primefaces, mojarra

Recently I switched to mojarra from myfaces and noticed that primefaces datatable checkbox multiple row selection is not working.

I have tried the exact sample program available at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf

With myfaces both single and multiple selection are working ,but with mojarra multiple selection is not working(selectedCars.length is 0 in setSelectedCars method)

I have tried with mojarra 2.0.3 and mojarra 2.1.0 with primefaces 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 'f:view contentType="text/html"' solved the problem.

Read this in http://www.primefaces.org/faq.html

Answer (score -2):

```
           <p:column sortBy="#{tup.docTypeAndDirection}" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Document Type"/>

                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{tup.docTypeAndDirection}"/>
          </p:column>

          <p:column sortBy="#{tup.partnerEDIAddress}" >
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Partner Trading Address"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{tup.partnerEDIQual}:#{tup.partEDIAddr}"></h:outputText>
          </p:column>                   
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Any context? Otherwise it is very hard to understand this answer (and also post version info, is this explicitly for the JSF and PF version mentioned in the question?)