# Primefaces dataTable with checkbox not work

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, datatable, jsf-2.2

I am using Primefaces 4.0 with jsf2.2.

When I use dataTable with checkbox, it won't send back any record whenever I select records.

It supposed to send back the record once I click the checkbox.

I remove extra stuff and make my code simple to test it:

There is a polling printing selected items every second, so that I can check is there something sent back.

And after doing this, I found there's nothing sent back.
Here's my code:

Page:

```
<h:head>
    <title>System Monitor</title>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{indexBean.printSelect()}"/> 
    </h:form> 

    <h:form>     

        <p:dataTable id='data' var="proc" value="#{indexBean.procStatus}"
                     rowKey="#{proc.pid}" selection="#{indexBean.selectedProcs}">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name='header'>
                    <h:outputText value='Process Name'/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputCell" id="pname" value='#{proc.name}'/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "indexBean")
@ViewScoped
public class indexBean implements Serializable {
private ProcStatDataModel procStatus;
private SingleProcess[] selectedProcs;

@PostConstruct
public void loadProcStat() {
    List<SingleProcess> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test1"));
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test2"));
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test3"));
    procStatus = new ProcStatDataModel(temp);
}

public void printSelect() {
    if (selectedProcs != null) {
        String str = "";
        for (SingleProcess sp : selectedProcs) {
            str += sp.getName() + "_";
        }
        System.out.print(str);
    } else {
        System.out.println("selectedProcs is null");
    }
}

public ProcStatDataModel getProcStatus() {
    return procStatus;
}

public SingleProcess[] getSelectedProcs() {
    return selectedProcs;
}

public void setSelectedProcs(SingleProcess[] selectedProcs) {
    this.selectedProcs = selectedProcs;
}
}
```

I've tried attaching `rowCheckListener` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650546/checkbox-datatable-primefaces-doesnt-working) before but in vain.

Also, I tried adding `f:view contentType="text/html"` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569502/primefaces-datatable-selectionmode-multiple-not-working-with-mojarra) and it was not help.

It's weird because I do the same thing with the case of [primefaces show case](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf) and it acts as I think. So I think this approach is OK, there should be something wrong in my code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you debug the code, where do you get the error? Does it enter to setSelectedProcs()? And, you do not set any pid in your bean. Maybe the bean cannot locate your row by pid? My eclipse did not validate ' instead of ", but I don't know if its relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes and it worked. Not sure, which one is the solution.

1) Changed all the ' to ".

2) Datatable's `value="#{indexBean.procStatus}"` is wrong i think. I changed it to the name of the ArrayList inside the class. So, it became `value="#{indexBean.procStatus.mylist}"`

3) Added an ajax listener, like the one you mentioned in the question. `<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{indexBean.check}"   />`.

4) Added `pid` to the constructor which will be our rowKey.

5) Now, the poll prints the array.

Resultin xhtml is as follows:

```
<h:head>
    <title>System Monitor</title>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{indexBean.printSelect()}"/> 
    </h:form> 

    <h:form>     

        <p:dataTable id="data" var="proc" value="#{indexBean.procStatus.mylist}"
                     rowKey="#{proc.pid}" selection="#{indexBean.selectedProcs}">
                     <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{indexBean.check}"   />
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Process Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText styleClass="outputCell" id="pname" value="#{proc.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "indexBean")
@ViewScoped
public class indexBean implements Serializable {
private ProcStatDataModel procStatus;
private SingleProcess[] selectedProcs;

@PostConstruct
public void loadProcStat() {
    List<SingleProcess> temp = new ArrayList<SingleProcess>();
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test1",1));
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test2",2));
    temp.add(new SingleProcess("test3",3));
    procStatus = new ProcStatDataModel(temp);
}

public void printSelect() {
    if (selectedProcs != null) {
        String str = "";
        for (SingleProcess sp : selectedProcs) {
            str += sp.getName() + "_";
        }
        System.out.print(str);
    } else {
        System.out.println("selectedProcs is null");
    }
}

public ProcStatDataModel getProcStatus() {
    return procStatus;
}

public SingleProcess[] getSelectedProcs() {
    return selectedProcs;
}

public void setSelectedProcs(SingleProcess[] selectedProcs) {
    this.selectedProcs = selectedProcs;
}
public void check(SelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("in check");
}
}
```

Comment: I did what you said in 3 & 4(Because I don't understand what do you mean in 1 and 2) and it fix the problem.

However, when it comes to my project (which is more complex), the checkbox send the information several seconds(even minutes) after I click the checkbox. I am wondering if this is about performance? But the polling still invoked during this time(send back time), so I don't know if there's something wrong...

Comment: Can you check where the problem is for me?

I have no idea why it doesn't work and I am going crazy..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3aTdDblJJei1IeHc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for the wrong file above, here's the right one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ye4CP3K_a3cTZFV3l2SHhYTGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I had the same problem.. your Number 3 fixed it.